# Spring JPA use Specification as from for other select

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to wrap a Specification result as a new from.
In native SQL the select would look like:

```
SELECT sample_alias.*
FROM 
    (SELECT sample.*
    FROM sample
    WHERE 1=1 AND ... --custom filters)
    as sample_alias
JOIN B b
--orders, limits, other filters etc.
```

Where table 'sample' has a corresponding entity Sample in Hibernate.

```
SELECT sample.*
    FROM sample
    WHERE 1=1 AND ... --custom filters
```

is prepared by toWhereClause.

```
/**
 * Wrap specifications into a from for new specification.
 * Current solution uses IN for ids
 * @param internalCause where clause result
 * @return
 */
protected Specification<Sample> toWrapperClause(Specification<Sample> internalCause) {
        return (root, query, cb) -> {
            Subquery sub = query.subquery(root.getJavaType());
            Root subroot = sub.from(root.getJavaType());
            Specification whereClause = internalCause;
            sub.where(whereClause.toPredicate(subroot, query, cb));
            sub.select(subroot.get(Sample_.ID));
            Predicate in = root.get(Sample_.ID).in(sub);
            return cb.and(in);
        };
    }

protected Specification<Sample> toWhereClause(){
    //custom builder executed. logics for internal block 
    return specifications;
}
```

I have a viable reseason for using such a native sql-construction: I need to use both distinct and order by on fields that are not present in output result.

Is it possible to be done using Specification?

Comment: Why do you want to express this as a inline view and not just a combination of filters?

AFAIK inline views of this kind are not possible in Criteria API.

Comment: @Jens Schauder Basicly, beacuse I need to use distict in filter & order by fields that are not present in select. Example: select distinct a.* from table_a a join table_b b  join table_c c where b.=XXX order by c.myfield

Comment: @Jens Schauder I'm currently using a subquery with IN clause instead: select a.* from table_a a join table_c c where a.id in (select a.id from table_a join table_b b where b.=XXX)  order by c.myfield. That solves my problem, but causes some boilerplate code with subquery. I wondered, if there was a way around.